# One PC as server for an SqlBase database

Tags: sqlbase, guptateamdeveloper

Can any guide me on how (if possible) to set up an PC as a server for e multi user use.  I have a 5 user license for SqlBase, an multi user application made under Team delveloper (Gupta).

What do I need, if anything in addition?

How to set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming 1) all the Client PC's you want to connect to SQLBase server are networked , and 2) you have installed SQLBase on the PC Server ( either as a Service or not - matters not ), and 3) you have installed the TeamDeveloper run-time files + application files on each client ( i.e. the 'Deploy' package that comes with TD ), and 4) you want to use Gupta's native SQLBase router ( not ODBC ) , and 5) You have Created the appropriate Database on the Server ( See all SQLBase Guides here: [SQLBase Manuals - All versions](http://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/)   ,  then simply configure SQL.ini on each the client to point to the same database as the TD app requires some thing like :

```
;----------------------------------------------------------
; SQLBase INItialization file for Windows CLIENT  x32 bit
;----------------------------------------------------------
;
;
[win32client]
;An appropriate client name goes here
clientname=MyName

[win32client.dll]
comdll=sqlws32

[win32client.ws32]
serverpath=<SQLBASE_SERVER_NAME_HERE>,localhost/*
```

You can easily test connectivity from Client to Server via SQLTalk run from the client. Try connecting to the Database:

```
Set Server <SQLBASE_SERVER_NAME_HERE> ;
Connect <DATABASE NAME> SYSADM/SYSADM;
Select * from <TABLE NAME>
```

Comment: hi and thanks.  One more question, can I use www.noip.com/  I see they offer this free?  What is downside with this compared to a bought one and how many IP addresses do you get from noip.com?  If all is free, how do they make money?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Never heard of it. Not sure what it has to do with SQLBase.